# how to switch or fade huge amount of maps with leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I have a bulk of historical maps of the same area to show with leaflet. I'd like to choose the maps with a hierarchical menu and then fade in or out the single maps when needed. I did not find that control.

What do you consider 'best practice' for showing a large amount of different maps for comparison?

If I include all of the maps in ordinary layers or overlays, the popup menu grows far to large. So I created several pages with special mixes of charts. But there often are needs to compare with maps, which are not yet available together. So I really would like to have one page to choose from them all.

You may want to look at the current resulting single pages:

- https://karten.geschichtswerkstatt-holzwickede.de/Holzwickede/index.html
- https://karten.geschichtswerkstatt-holzwickede.de/luftbilder-rvr.html
- https://karten.geschichtswerkstatt-holzwickede.de/Holzwickede-1855/index.html

Is there anyone who knows an apropriate extension or likes to share experience and time to create this extension in a team?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#layer-switching-controls and https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.FadeOut

Answer (score 0):

The best example I know of a single page showing many different maps is [leaflet-providers](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/).

Plus, the code is on [github](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers), so you could probably adapt it to your needs.